# How to operate between 2D lists in Python in a loop?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, 2d

so basically I create a program that based on the user input of house coordinates (x,y), it will assign an optimal spot in R2 for a police station to be built based on the average manhattan distance. Obviously, the less the better.
Here is what I've already written:

```
L=[]
K=[]
Kx=[]
Ky=[]
NoHouses=int(input("How many houses are there? : "))

for i in range(1,NoHouses+1):
      plot1 = input("coordinate(x, y) for house" +str(i)+" :").split()
      plot1 = [int(i) for i in plot1]
      K.append(plot1)
      Kx.append(plot1[0])
      Ky.append(plot1[1])
      Ky.sort()
      Kx.sort()
for i in range(Kx[0],Kx[-1]+1):
    for j in range(Ky[0],Ky[-1]+1):
        L.append([i,j])
        print("House Coordinates: ",(K))
print("List of x coordinate: ",(Kx))
print("List of y coordinates: ",(Ky))
print("Possible police station coordinates: ",(L))
```

basically what I try to do is to find the manhattan distances from the possible police station coordinate to the houses given by the user. So in the end I should be left with a list "D" that has len(L)==len(D) (num of police station coordinates== num of manhattan distances) , which then I will sort and find the minimum . The problem I face is finding those manhattan distances for each possible police station coordinates. What am I doing wrong? While I expected the output to be len(L) it seems to be random. Below is what I've tried :

```
D=[]
K=[[1,2],[2,2]] #test case
L=[[1,1],[2,6]]  #testcase
def manhattan_distance(point1,point2):
    return sum(abs(value1 - value2) for value1, value2 in zip(point1,point2))
for i in range(len(L)):
    for j in range(len(K)):
       x1=L[i]
       x2=K[j]
       D.append(manhattan_distance(x1,x2))
print(manhattan_distance(x1,x2))
print(D)
```

Comment: [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you attached worked for 1 coordinate pair. For multiple coordinate pairs you kept appending to `D` instead of creating a new `D2` for the new value of the coordinates. For multiple values of coordinate pairs I would suggest the following:

```
D=[]
K=[[1,2], [2,9]] #test case
L=[[1,1],[2,6], [4,5]]  #testcase
def manhattan_distance(point1,point2):
    return sum(abs(value1 - value2) for value1, value2 in zip(point1,point2))

D = {}
for ii, k in enumerate(K):
    temp = []
    for l in L:
       temp.append(manhattan_distance(l,k))
    D[ii] = temp
print(D)  # {0: [1, 5, 6], 1: [9, 3, 6]}
```

This will create a dictionary with a list per coordinate pair in K.

However, you can do the same without the for loops, thus improving runtime drastically for large L values. To do so, we will use the `numpy` package. The idea is to compute everything at once using vector calculation instead of running the for loop. Using the same data as above, we can do the following:

```
L = np.array(L)
K = np.array(K)
```

Now `L` is a (?,2) shapes array holding all the coordinates and K is a (2,) 1 dimensional array. By performing subtraction as follows:

```
temp = L - K
```

What happens is that `numpy` broadcasts `K` to all rows of `L`, performing the subtraction to all rows at the same time. Then, performing absolute and summing over the column dimension will result in the wanted D value:

```
D = {}
for ii, k in enumerate(K):
    temp = np.sum(np.abs(L - k), axis=1)
    D[ii] = list(temp)
print(D)
```

If you want it in list type you can then convert the `numpy array` back to list.

Running both version with L which has a size of (100000, 2) using `%%timeit` resulted in:

1. Using the for loop approach, it took `282 ms ± 6.71 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`
2. Using numpy, it took `17.4 ms ± 646 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)`

An order of magnitude faster.